# How can I see the source code of deque module from Python's collections library?

Tags: python, deque

I tried using inspect.getsource(deque) and while it works on other modules from collections, running it on deque throws an error "could not find class definition". Why does this happen only to deque and how can I see it's source code?

Comment: It's not only for deque, you will probably see the same for other C implemented types such as `defaultdict`.

Comment: Also, instead of `inspect.getsource` you may see the `__file__` attribute on the modules, and check the source files directly on your programing editor. However it won't work for `collections.deque` as it is defined in C, as per the answer given.

Answer (score 7):

This one is implemented in C code for CPython, and the collections python module just [imports that name](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L30).  Depending on your Python version and installation, you may find somewhere on your system a file called `_collections.so` or `_collectionsmodule.so` which has the real implementation, but `inspect.getsource` is not really smart enough to figure that out.

You can find the sources here:

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c